# Ошибка при парсинге сайтов на pycharm

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, pycharm

[image: При попытке достать код этого сайта все хорохо]
[image: но если попробовать вставить эту ссылку у меня вылезает много ошибок]
При попытке достать код сайта вылезает множество ошибок, но если поменять сайт то всё заработает, код ошибки ниже

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "D:\Projects. Pycharm\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1374, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\Projects. Pycharm\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "D:\Projects. Pycharm\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "D:\Projects. Pycharm\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1374, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\Projects. Pycharm\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "D:\Projects. Pycharm\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 287, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\parsing\TEST PARSING.py", line 4, in <module>
    url = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: Видимо сайт знает, что вы бот. Код и ошибки текстом, а не скриншотами, если хотите, чтоб вам помогли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вот так

```
import requests

url = 'https://tursportopt.ru/category/rybolovnye-tovary-optom/'

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0',
    }
)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Возможно ли как то немного поправить мой код и что бы заработало (Я только начал парсить)